# How I can call function with one parameter (DataGrid or DataGridComboBoxColumn)?

Tags: c#, c++, ellipsis

I write code and want call function with one parameter (DataGrid or DataGridComboBoxColumn).
How I can do this ?

```
 public void dyscyplina_pobierz(DataGrid dg) //or DataGridComboBoxColumn
        {
            String tresc = "Data source=ADAM_LAPTOP; Integrated Security=true; Database=astruzik";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(tresc);
            SqlCommand polecenie = new SqlCommand("select Nazwa from Dyscyplina order by Nazwa ASC", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(polecenie);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Dyscyplina");
            DataRow napis = null;
            if (flags1 == false)
            {
                int licznik = ds.Tables["Dyscyplina"].Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < licznik; i++)
                {
                    napis = ds.Tables["Dyscyplina"].Rows[i];
                    listadyscyplina.Add(napis.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString());
                }
            }
            dg.ItemsSource = listadyscyplina;
            flags1 = true;
        }
```

Comment: `...` denotes a variable number of arguments, not an argument of indeterminate type.

Comment: It's really hard to understand your question for someone who doesn't know anything about `C++`.You could be more clear

Comment: Also, why don't you simply return the `listadyscyplina` variable instead? You're in the managed world now, returning instances is no longer black magic. When you're calling the method later, you can simply call either `dg.ItemsSource = dyscyplina_pobierz();` or whatever else you need.

Comment: FYI, this is not C++, so I suggest your remove the C++ tag.  C# and C++ are two different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) parameter modifier.

```
public int Sum(params int[] integers)
{
    int sum=0;

    foreach (var x in integers)
    {
        sum += x;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Usage

```
var sum = Sum(1,2,3,4) // 10
```

Also

```
var myArrayOfIntegers = new int[] {
    1,2,3,4
};

var sum = Sum(myArrayOfIntegers); // still 10
```